# Google PageSpeed Eliminate render-blocking CSS in above-the-fold content Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a website [www.nursecpdonline.com.au](http://www.nursecpdonline.com.au); it's fully responsive.

The problem I am having now is rendering the stylesheets. I know I'm supposed to create a critical `CSS` and inline it in the page.

However, the problem I am having is all the `<link rel="stylesheets">` are causing render-blocking above the fold errors in **PageSpeed** and knowing google will penalise the SEO rankings for that as well.

I am at a loss as to how to fix it, I have tried all sorts of WordPress plugins but they just seem to break my site.

I managed to fix the JS by adding async via a plugin in WordPress.

I have read somewhere that you can't have `<link rel="stylesheet">` anywhere but in the  tag if this is the case how does anyone solve this rendering issue for css?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code provides an example to Eliminate render-blocking CSS. See if you can adjust it to suit your case.

```
// append css dynamically to head
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
var element = document.createElement('link');
element.rel = 'stylesheet';
element.type = 'text/css';
element.href = '//www.link-to-your-css-file.com/my.css';

// append the css file to the head
element.media = 'non-existant-media';
head.appendChild(element, head.firstChild);
setTimeout(function () {
    element.media = 'all';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know where this code would go in wordpress? Like in the header.php or somewhere in the functions file?

Comment: This is JavaScript so you would have to add this to a .js file and adjust it to suit your site. Then you would have to load this JS file first thing before any CSS is loaded. Every site is different so you will need an expert to see how to best apply this.